# Determine the distribution of a random variable $X=a_1X_1+...+a_nX_n+b$ where $a_1,...,a_n,b\in\mathbb R$.

Tags: probability

Random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and $X_i:\mathcal N(u_i,\sigma_i^2),i=1,...,n$. Determine the distribution of a random variable $X=a_1X_1+...+a_nX_n+b$ where $a_1,...,a_n,b\in\mathbb R$.

Could someone show the procedure for this problem?

Comment: I think the sum of independent normal random variables is still normal.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Consider characteristic functions

Comment: You ask "Could someone show the procedure for this problem?", and I in turn ask of you  "Could you show the work you've done on this problem?"

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Show that if $X$ is normal then  $Z=\alpha X$ is normal, and find its parameters
- Show that  if $X$ is normal then $Z=X+\beta$ is normal, and find its parameters.
- Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are normal and independent, then $Z=X+Y$ is normal, and find its parameters

Then put all together.